# I want to print Insufficient data in the place of value error and continue with the for loop ? how can it be done?

Tags: python, python-3.x, machine-learning, data-science, linear-regression

**I have code which throws a value error if the sample size is less than 5. i wanted to add a comment as Insufficent data in the place of value error and if the sample size is greater than or equal to 5 i want to continue with the code.This is the code that i have written and it doesnt work .
**Please help me in modifying the above code**

````
df_names = []

comp1={}
for j in bentonite:
    if len(j)<5:
        print('Insufficient data')
    else:
        continue
        for i in j:
            if i!='component_id':
                X=j.drop([i,'component_id'],axis=1) 
                y = j[i]
                if i == 'loi_':
                    break 

                sc=StandardScaler()
                X=sc.fit_transform(X)
                X = pd.DataFrame(X)

                from sklearn.model_selection import KFold 
                from sklearn import metrics
                n_split = 5 
                kf=KFold(n_splits=n_split,shuffle=True,random_state=0) 

                for model,name in zip([lm],['lm']):
                    rmse_test=[]
                    r2_test=[]
                    adj_r2_test=[]
                    rmse_train=[]
                    r2_train=[]
                    adj_r2_train=[]
                    
                    for train,test in kf.split(X,y):
                        X_train,X_test=X.iloc[train,:],X.iloc[test,:]
                        y_train,y_test=y.iloc[train],y.iloc[test]
                        model.fit(X_train,y_train) #fitting the model
                        y_predict_test=model.predict(X_test) #predicting the test result
                        mse_test=round(metrics.mean_squared_error(y_test,y_predict_test),3) #calculating mse
                        rmse_test.append(np.sqrt(mse_test)) # calculating rmse for test
                        rSquare_test = round(r2_score((y_test),(y_predict_test)),3) #calculating rsquared for test
                        adj_rsquare_test= round(1-(1-rSquare_test)*(len(y)-1)/(len(y)-X.shape[1]-1),3) #calculating adjusted r2 for test
                        r2_test.append(rSquare_test) #appending the result to the empty list
                        adj_r2_test.append(adj_rsquare_test) #appending the result to the empty list

                        y_predict_train=model.predict(X_train) #predicting the result for train
                        mse_train=round(metrics.mean_squared_error(y_train,y_predict_train),3) #calculating mse for train
                        rmse_train.append(np.sqrt(mse_train)) # calculating rmse for train
                        rSquare_train = round(r2_score((y_train),(y_predict_train)),3) #calculating rsquared for train
                        adj_rsquare_train= round(1-(1-rSquare_train)*(len(y)-1)/(len(y)-X.shape[1]-1),3) #calculating adjusted r2 for train
                        r2_train.append(rSquare_train) #appending the result to the empty list
                        adj_r2_train.append(adj_rsquare_train) #appending the result to the empty list
                
                
                    exec(f"df_{name}_{i} = pd.DataFrame()")
                    exec(f"df_{name}_{i}['Name'] =[name]*n_split")
                    exec(f"df_{name}_{i}['rmse_train'] =rmse_train")
                    exec(f"df_{name}_{i}['rmse_test'] =rmse_test")
                    exec(f"df_{name}_{i}['r2_train'] =r2_train")
                    exec(f"df_{name}_{i}['r2_test'] =r2_test")
                    exec(f"df_{name}_{i}['adj_r2_train'] =adj_r2_train")
                    exec(f"df_{name}_{i}['adj_r2_test'] =adj_r2_test")
                    exec(f"df_{name}_{i}['output'] = [i]*n_split")
                    df_names.append(f"df_{name}_{i}")
            
            
    collection = pd.DataFrame() #collecting the results in dataframe

    for nn in df_names:
        exec(f"collection=pd.concat([collection,{nn}])")

        collection['new_name'] = collection['output']


    df4 = collection.groupby(['new_name']).mean()

#finding the mean of the results to find the overall best model
#df4['Mean'] = (df4['rmse_train'] + df4['rmse_test'] + (1-df4['r_squared_train']) + (1-df4['r_squared_test']))/4
#df4.sort_values(by='Mean',inplace=True)

    abc = list(d2.columns)

    new = pd.DataFrame(columns=df4.columns)
    for names in range(len(abc)):
        val = df4[df4.index.isin([i for i in df4.index if abc[names] in i])].iloc[0,:]
        df5=pd.DataFrame(val.values.reshape(1,-1),columns=new.columns,index=[val.name])
        new=pd.concat([new,df5])           
    
    comp=j.component_id.unique()[0]
    comp1[comp]=new
    print('\n')
    print('\033[1m'+ comp+':')
    print('\n')
    print(new)
    print('\n')
    ```
````

Comment: This: `exec(f"df_{name}_{i} = pd.DataFrame()")` is very unusual and should not be done.  Instead you should make a dict containing values keyed by name, such as `df_dict[f'{name}_{i}'] = pd.DataFrame()`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `continue` statement is misplaced. It means, "stop the current iteration here and **continue** with the loop with the next iteration". So to skip the cases with few data points, you need to put that statement directly after `print`, and **not** in a separate `else` block.

```
for j in bentonite:
    if len(j)<5:
        print('Insufficient data')
        continue
    for i in j:
        ...
```

Another, equivalent option would be to keep the `else` statement, but removing `continue`.

```
for j in bentonite:
    if len(j)<5:
        print('Insufficient data')
    else:
        for i in j:
            ...
```